# Problem with php script that try to read file while Powerhell writes to it

Tags: php, apache, powershell

I have a big problem with a apache server running PHP.
Often some PHP scripts is trying to get data from a CSV file while a Powershell script writes to it.
Is there a common way to prevent this?
I have tied to write to the file at a specific time and then read from the file while no writing is done. But even when I set a read error in the PHP to 20 sec. it often try to read an write at the same time.... HELP!

Comment: Can you give the code that read the file in PHP, Do you use `fopen()` and `fRead()` or just `readFile()`? The first option gives you more options and certainly a way to prevent lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cant add a simple comment because I dont have reputation points... Don't understand that logic but whatever. The most common way of resolving this is using a lock file to signal to another process that the file is in use, check out this little guide:
[locking-files-with-flock](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/8/11/0/locking-files-with-flock)